Laravel 11 application behaving slowly when database is not local
I have a simple laravel 11 application running on php 8.3, and i only change the db (mysql) settings via the .env file when im using local db (127.0.0.1) everything is extremly fast i logged the query time and it can be seen here:
 [2024-06-12 22:05:42] local.INFO: select * from w_users where id = ? limit 1 {"bindings":[1],"time":4.1}
 [2024-06-12 22:05:42] local.INFO: select * from w_users where w_users.id = ? limit 1 {"bindings":[1],"time":1.49}

later i switched to an external db provider (digital ocean) and i noticed that the page is very slow here are the results i logged:
[2024-06-12 22:07:03] local.INFO: select * from w_users where id = ? limit 1 {"bindings":[1],"time":1228.27} 
[2024-06-12 22:07:03] local.INFO: select * from w_users where w_users.id = ? limit 1 {"bindings":[1],"time":352.72}

i tried several cloud db vendors but its always extremely slow what can be done?
note: both databases (the local and the remote are generated using the same script and both are empty not having data)
my architecture requires several laravel instances behind load balancer accessing a common remote db

Network connection speed plays a significant part when connecting to any remote resources. There is not much you can do about that.

Try using ping to test the latency from your application's host to the remote database host. Then compare that to the latency of ping 127.0.0.1. Do you see a difference?

I was not able to find a solution, i ended up using a dedicated ec2 with mysql running on it, being on the same network the application now works fast as expected
